# error: variable total might not have been initialized

Tags: java, variables

I get this error but when I initialized it with 0 I always get an answer 0 in my amountToPay textfield and not computing the if statement please help me. I want to display the result/sum of the two textfield in amountToPay text field.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
    int total;
       
            
    if (productCode.equals("1")){
    total = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()) * 250;
    }else if (productCode.equals("2")){
    total = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()) * 200;
    }else if (productCode.equals("3")){
    total = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()) * 500;
    }else if (productCode.equals("4")){
    total = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()) * 100;
    }
    amountToPay.setText(String.valueOf(total));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because variable `total` will not be initialized if `productCode`'s actual value is not one of the handled ones (`"1"`,`"2"`,`"3"` or `"4"`). It is not clear what you expect your code to do when `productCode` is for example `"5"` or an empty string `""`.

A better approach would be the use of a `switch` statement. This will help you solve the problem at hand *and* make your code more readable, by explicitly handling a `default` case (when `productCode` value is not expected).

```java
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        int total;

        switch (productCode) {
            case "1":
                total = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()) * 250;
                break;
            case "2":
                total = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()) * 200;
                break;
            case "3":
                total = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()) * 500;
                break;
            case "4":
                total = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText()) * 100;
                break;
            default:
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()).log(Level.WARNING, "Unhandled product code: " + productCode);
                total = 0;//A default value when productCode value is not expected/handled
                break;
        }
        amountToPay.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    }
```